# Custom sorting ListBox items in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have some custom filenames I need to sort based on information in the filename itself.

I know there has to be an easier way than I have come up with (a for loop which goes through and manually splits the strings to identify the various filename info) using **SortDescriptions** but I can't figure them out.

The filename format is:

OurApp_versionNum_DEBUG_build_number.exe

e.g.

Notepad_1.0_DEBUG_build_1.exe

I want to sort the items with the highest build number at the top of the list box so e.g.

Notepad_1.0_DEBUG_build_**10**.exe

Notepad_1.0_DEBUG_build_**7**.exe

Notepad_1.0_DEBUG_build_**1**.exe

I know there must be a simpler way than what I've come up with. Any help is appreciated.

I am using .NET 4.0.

Thank you

m

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sort the items before adding them to the listbox. A simple regex call could extract the number such as: `(\\d+).exe` if you know that's exactly how the file names will be.

Comment: I ended up doing something like this. Straight forward for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a customized natural sorting algorithm. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp) for an example implementation (the native `C#` one, by the author J.D.).

Definition from [wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order)

> Natural sort order is an ordering of strings in alphabetical order, except that multi-digit numbers are ordered as a single character

Unmodified, it will output your list as:

> - Notepad_1.0_DEBUG_build_1.exe
> - Notepad_1.0_DEBUG_build_7.exe
> - Notepad_1.0_DEBUG_build_10.exe

If all your entries have the same prefix, you can use just use the reverse comparison function:

```
public static int CompareNaturalReverse(string strA, string strB) {
    return -CompareNatural(strA, strB);
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to maintain the alphabetical order and onlye reverse the numerical order (because of different prefixes), you have to change the sorting implementation.